# MySQL Select substituir um código por uma informação

Tags: mysql

Eu tenho duas situações na busca dentro do MySQL que necessito trocar o código por um dado literal.

Campo: Pgto (dados possíveis: S ou N)

Na busca se o campo Pgto for N eu exibo na tela Não e se for S eu exibo Sim.

A outra situação é o campo Status (dados possíveis: 1, 2, 3 e 4), na qual se na busca for 1 eu exibo Pendente de Pgto, se for 2 eu exibo Liberado, e assim por diante.

Como faço isso dentro do Select do MySQL.

Comment: Brenno, verifica se o case te atende: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp

Answer (score 0):

Ola,

Podes usar as funções if do MySql ou até mesmo CASE,

```
SELECT Pgto,
CASE
    WHEN Pgto = 'S' THEN "Sim"
    ELSE "Não"
END
FROM a_tua_tabela;
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN Pgto = 'S' THEN 'Sim'
    ELSE 'Não'
END AS Pgto,
CASE
    WHEN Status = 1 THEN 'Pendente de Pgto'
    WHEN Status = 2 THEN 'Liberado'
    WHEN Status = 3 THEN 'A caminho'
    WHEN Status = 4 THEN 'Entregue'
    ELSE 'Não definido'
END AS Status
FROM ...
```

Com o Case When você consegue passar N when para que te atenda da forma que achar necessário.